# Shopping Cart Thumbnails not showing

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, magento2.3, thumbnail

Have a little problem with my M2 V <sup>2.3.</sup>
In the shopping cart the thumbnails image is not displayed.

I can see that it gets a `404` for the image and when I look ind the `pub/media` I can not find the requested path for the image.

All other images are working fine. The only problem is in the shopping cart.

http://kasperstestdev.prod42.magentohotel.dk/

Sit is still in development.

Comment: looks like the path for the image is wrong:
The reguested path for this product is:
src="http://kasperstestdev.prod42.magentohotel.dk/pub/media/product/909d30f/alimar-130x50-cm-basalt-gneiss.jpg"

The right path is not the folder /909d304/ but /909d9e4/

How and where do I change this?

Comment: I check your website and it's working fine

Comment: Could you make a print screen?

Answer (score 0):

Run this **`command`**

> **`sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/magento/media`**

Comment: How do I do this via Putty SSH?

Comment: Did not solve the problem unfortnatly.

Comment: yes via putty. did you try flushing cache?

Comment: Yes have tried it all.
Have looked a bit closer and the regusted path for the image that gives a 404 does not exist in  the pub/media/produc/ folder.
If I use a placeholder image the image is displayed in the cart.

Comment: hmm... that should be image caching problem

Comment: that's kind of weird because I run into same kind of problem before and the command on top solves the issue .. 
try running **`indexer:reindex`**

Comment: have fixed the issue and it seems to be an extension that was trying to make SEO friendly urls for the images.
After disable this it works fine again.
Did not get any error in the log so pretty hard to find.